# Python - split string array to json

Tags: python

I have a string list (value) of a particular key like below

```
"versions": [
     "aaa/bbb/202007/cc/dd/v20",
     "aaa/bbb/202007/cc/dd/v22",
     "aaa/bbb/202007/cc/dd/v35",
     "aaa/bbb/202008/cc/dd/v15",
     "aaa/bbb/202008/cc/dd/v20",
     "aaa/bbb/202009/cc/dd/v5",
     "aaa/bbb/202009/cc/dd/v8"
]
```

Need this to be converted like below JSON like below

```
{
    "2020" : {
                 "07": {"v20", "v22", "v35"},
                 "08": {"v15", "v20"},
                 "09": {"v5", "v8"}
             },
}
```

What would be the best way to do this in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
versions= [
     "aaa/bbb/202007/cc/dd/v20",
     "aaa/bbb/202007/cc/dd/v22",
     "aaa/bbb/202007/cc/dd/v35",
     "aaa/bbb/202008/cc/dd/v15",
     "aaa/bbb/202008/cc/dd/v20",
     "aaa/bbb/202009/cc/dd/v5",
     "aaa/bbb/202009/cc/dd/v8"
]

import json

result = dict()
for s in versions:
    l = s.split('/')
    if not l[2][:4] in result:
        result[l[2][:4]] = dict()
    if not l[2][4:] in result[l[2][:4]]:
        result[l[2][:4]][l[2][4:]] = []
    result[l[2][:4]][l[2][4:]].append(l[5])
json.dumps(result)
```

returning:

```
'{"2020": {"07": ["v20", "v22", "v35"], "08": ["v15", "v20"], "09": ["v5", "v8"]}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Being a list, here's what a reducer can do with it. Easily destructure your list elements split by slashes and process the individual chunks.

`reduce` takes in a function to collect your results into a format (in your case JSON object / dict) and the list itself. The third param `{}` is an empty dict (or JSON object) wherein you process and add your data - its called accumulator. End of it, you'll get the accumulated value as result.

```
from functools import reduce

arr = [
    "aaa/bbb/202007/cc/dd/v20",
    "aaa/bbb/202007/cc/dd/v22",
    "aaa/bbb/202007/cc/dd/v35",
    "aaa/bbb/202008/cc/dd/v15",
    "aaa/bbb/202008/cc/dd/v20",
    "aaa/bbb/202009/cc/dd/v5",
    "aaa/bbb/202009/cc/dd/v8"
]


def convert(my_dict, entry):
    p, q, year, s, t, version = entry.split("/")
    key, internal_key = year[:4], year[4:]
    top_level_dict = my_dict.get(key, {})

    interim_dict = top_level_dict.get(internal_key, set())
    interim_dict.add(version)

    top_level_dict[internal_key] = interim_dict
    my_dict[key] = top_level_dict
    return my_dict

print(reduce(convert, arr, {}))
```

And the result:

```
{'2020': {'07': {'v22', 'v20', 'v35'}, '08': {'v15', 'v20'}, '09': {'v8', 'v5'}}}
```